# How to embed an Http server (like i-Jetty, Paw, etc) in android application

Tags: android, httpserver

How can I integrate an HTTP server (like iJetty, Paw, etc) in my Android application? I can't find any useful tutorial on the Internet. Most of the websites (including the official ones) just provide the server specification and downloadable server jar files. I was looking for some Java code to integrate that file in my Eclipse project so that it could be used as server component in my application. Any help please?

Comment: Just wondering, why do you need an HTTP server in a device that's designed to be a CLIENT? No trolling, I'm really curious.

Comment: I am looking for one too. I have a small Android device designed to be plugged into a TV. I would like it to have a jetty like server so I can run servlets to provide a web service.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's one I have successfully used:

**NanoHttpd**

- https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NanoHTTPD

> NanoHttpd is an open-source, small-footprint web server that is suitable for embedding in applications, written in the Java programming language. The source code consists of a single .java file.

And here is an Android sample project that uses it:

https://gist.github.com/komamitsu/1893396

It's very small and simple and in pure java but it is fairly modifiable. There are others but they are a bit more heavyweight. Depends what you want to do. I would recommend you start small and see if that suits your purposes.

Comment: I am using same nanohttpd

Comment: How about SSL support? I can't find any successful examples and feedback about nanohttpd and ssl.