# Which web server should I choice in Android when I upload and download file via web browser over WiFi?

Tags: android

I hope to write an android app with Android Studio, the app can download mobile phone files to PC, 
and also upload files to mobile phone from PC via web browser over wifi.

I have read some documents in http://stackoverflow.com, it seems that the app need to embed a web server in it .

There are some web servers which can run under Android, such as NanoHTTPD, AndroidAsync, PAW Server, AndroidWebServ...

Could you tell me which web server I should choice? Thanks!

Comment: Any web server that can run under Android should do the trick.

Comment: I hope to choice a suitable web server for download and upload files

Comment: Again, select the first one that you can get working on Android. If you can't choose one yourself, flip a coin or something. You're just wasting time right now by asking this question.

Comment: -1: This is a recommendation question with no specifics. To be a good question, it would need to provide specific requirements that the webserver needs to perform. Otherwise this is just "What’s your favorite Android webserver?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little more insight would help to understand what you are looking for. If you just need ANY server then stick to the comment of Stephan Branczyk and take the first one you like or able to run. Else, please specify your requirements. But please consider that stackoverflow shouldn't be a shortcut for reading the documentations (at least - that's what i think).

If I were writing an application in Android I would start with NanoHTTPD or i-jetty (https://github.com/jetty-project/i-jetty). At first glance, the two seem pretty easy to implement. A similar question on how to integrate a HTTP Server in Android was asked here: [How to embed an Http server (like i-Jetty, Paw, etc) in android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470090/how-to-embed-an-http-server-like-i-jetty-paw-etc-in-android-application).

AndroidAsync is a low level network protocol library - I don't think this is what you are looking for? For a higher http request library they recommend Ion (Only two links? -.- It's on github).

Also if your application is commercial you should check the respective licenses.

Answer (score 0):

This one is good: https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd

> NanoHTTPD – a tiny web server in Java
>
> NanoHTTPD is a light-weight HTTP server designed for embedding in
>   other applications, released under a Modified BSD licence.